# Spring data-jpa and exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Recently I had been discovered Spring Data Jpa. The one thing I was not able to make it working was proper exception translation to Spring's Exception hierarchy.

According to this [Spring Data JPA forces CGLib proxying to non repository classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745543/spring-data-jpa-forces-cglib-proxying-to-non-repository-classes) the `<jpa:repositories />` activates persistence exception translation for Spring beans annotated with @Repository. The reference documentation in this post points to spring-data-jpa 1.1.1.

But when you look at the docs for version 1.3.0 this paragraph has been removed. Also I was plying with `@Repository` annotation putting it wherever possible but with no success.

My question is: Is it possible to achieve proper exception translation with the recent spring-data-jpa lib version 1.3.0?

Ok. I will put some configuration here:

...

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:pbase"/>
  <property name="user" value="sa"/>
  <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="prjPersistenceUnit"></property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/mpersistence.xml"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"
              p:showSql="true"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.repository" />
```

Content of mpersistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="prjPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>Persistence unit which uses EclipseLink JPA 2.0 implementation.</description>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.mycompany.Setting</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle10g"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My rpository

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Setting, Long> {

    Setting findByNamee(String name);
}
```

Here findByNamee should rise some Spring database exception as a real property in the databese is name not namee. But I always get

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Though, when configuring a regular Dao object with `@Repository` annotation everything works as expected.

I am trying to deploy it on Tomcat 6.0 with eclipseLink 2.3.2.

Comment: It's not much help saying, but it is definitely possible. I use version 1.3.0 in my project, and I have a test asserting that exception translation works on my repository. Having `<jpa:repositories/>` should be enough. `JpaRepositoryConfigExtension` registers the bean post processor (`PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`) that looks for beans annotated with `@Repository`.

Comment: Can anybody point me out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could check some working example code I published since then at https://github.com/zagyi/examples/tree/master/spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thanks for providing an example but for some reason it still does not work for me, even though I am trying to do everything as in example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the EclipseLink Jpa Dialect to the EntityManagerFactory, because the exception translator is in the dialect.